# Setting style property on a div element

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following div element

```
<div style="color:#0000FF">
  <h3>This is a heading</h3>
  <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
</div>
```

Is there a way to change the style attribute of this div tag using JavaScript?.

specifically I want to do the following:

Set this style attribute to another string, eg `style = "test"`

create a new style attribute and replace this attribute with the new attribute

ie:

```
var new_style_a = document.createAttribute("style");
(somehow insert this new attribute into the div tag)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to get a JS reference to your div first - for simplicity's sake lets just give it an ID for now;

```
<div id='myDiv' style="color:#0000FF">
  <h3>This is a heading</h3>
  <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
</div>
```

Then in JS...

```
document.getElementById('myDiv').style.color = '#FF0000';
```

EDIT: To reflect your edited question. If you just want to set the value of an attribute to some string (for the record, not the best way to go if you're doing this to affect the style), you can do;

```
document.getElementById('myDiv').setAttribute('style','somestring');
```

EDIT AGAIN; If you insist on using `document.createAttribute`...

```
var attr = document.createAttribute('style');
attr.value = 'somestring';
document.getElementById('myDiv').setAttributeNode(attr);
```

Comment: what is I want to do something like this: 
var new_style_a = document.createAttribute("style");
(somehow insert this new attribute into the div tag)

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to change the style attribute of this div tag using
>   JavaScript?. specifically I want to do the following: Set this style
>   attribute to another string, eg style = "test"

If you want to replace the existing style attribute (or create one if not existing) on the element, then use:

```
document.getElementById('elemId').setAttribute('style','width:100px;');
```

If you want to add a new style property to the existing rules, then it would be like:

```
document.getElementById('elemId').style.setAttribute('width', '150px');
```

*You need to be able to refer to that `div`. Best is to give it a unique `id` and use `getElementById` to refer that.*

Answer (score -1):

You need to get JS to reference your div element by id.

**HTML**

```
<div id="elem-change" style="color:#0000FF">
  <h3>This is a heading</h3>
  <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
if (document.getElementById("elem-change")) {
         document.getElementById("elem-change").style.color = "#0000FF";
}
```

or

```
document.getElementById('elem-change').setAttribute('style','color :#0000FF');
```

**JQUERY**

```
$("#elem-change").css("color", "#0000FF");
```